# AJAX table filtering with more than one drop down select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Need a bit of help with my university project.

I'm trying to filter a table of results using AJAX. How do I re-structure the code below for use with 2 or more drop downs?
I've been doing hours of searching but I just can't seem to understand and I'm confusing myself.

The following code below does work however I don't understand fully the relation between the click event of the dropdown and passing the JSON data to the AJAX handler.

Perhaps I should use a on click event when selected? However I'm unsure how to go about this.

I particularly don't understand how "data:{query:query}," works in relation to the controller

Your help would be highly appreciated!

I'm using PHP and MYSQL on wordpress.

VIEW ###############################################

```
  <!-- Drop Down 1 --> 
  <div class="filter-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <select name="multi_search_filter" id="multi_search_filter" class="form- 
    control selectpicker">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="Michael">Michael</option>
    <option value="John">John</option>
    <option value="Smith">Smith</option>
    <option value="Tim">Tim</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_country" id="hidden_country" />
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Drop Down 2 --> 
  <div class="filter-group">
    <label>Year</label>
    <select name="multi_search_filter2" id="multi_search_filter2" class="form-control selectpicker">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_country2" id="hidden_country2" />
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
```

AJAX HANDLER #########################################

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query='')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"/ajax-index-test-fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#ul-table').html(data);
   }
  })
}


$('#multi_search_filter').change(function(){
 $('#hidden_country').val($('#multi_search_filter').val());

 var getSelectName = $('#hidden_country').val();
 var query = $('#hidden_country').val();
 load_data(query);

 console.log('the query is= ' + query);
});


});
```

MODEL/CONTROLLER  #########################################

```
 if($_POST["query"] != '')
 {

 $search_array = explode(",", $_POST["query"]);

 $search_text = "'" . implode("', '", $search_array) . "'";
 $query = "SELECT *
 FROM NominatorTBL
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Nominator_NomineeLinkTBL
 ON NominatorTBL.Nonimator_ID = Nominator_NomineeLinkTBL.Nonimator_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN  Nominee_ConfirmTBL
 ON Nominator_NomineeLinkTBL.Nominee_ID = Nominee_ConfirmTBL.Nominee_ID
 WHERE NominatorTBL.NomineeCategory1 = (".$search_text.")";

 } else {

 $query = "SELECT *
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Nominator_NomineeLinkTBL
 ON NominatorTBL.Nonimator_ID = Nominator_NomineeLinkTBL.Nonimator_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN  Nominee_ConfirmTBL
 ON Nominator_NomineeLinkTBL.Nominee_ID = Nominee_ConfirmTBL.Nominee_ID";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Let me try to explain

```
$('#multi_search_filter').change(function(){
 $('#hidden_country').val($('#multi_search_filter').val());

 var getSelectName = $('#hidden_country').val();
 var query = $('#hidden_country').val();
 load_data(query);

 console.log('the query is= ' + query);
});
```

On each your script is setting to a hidden input selected value and then use it value twice for assigning without changing them. That's not a good approach. Then call `load_data` function with this previously assigned value.

```
function load_data(query='')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"/ajax-index-test-fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#ul-table').html(data);
   }
  })
```

This function use `query` param or defaults it to '' if it wasn't provided and make api call with data {query:query}. So, answering your question first word query is parameter name and second word query is input param value which was provided with function call. For example if you will choose 'John' your object `{query:query}` will look like `{query: 'John'}`.

PS. I made few improvements for your `change` function:

```
$('#multi_search_filter').on('change', function(){
    const thisVal = $(this).val();
 $('#hidden_country').val(thisVal);
console.log('the query is= ' + thisVal);
     load_data(thisVal);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! Much appreciated!